# Bazaar pre-commit hook with parameter

Tags: python, bazaar, bazaar-plugins

I wrote a pre-commit hook for bazaar which checks some syntax issues in our code. Something similar to:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bialix/%2Bjunk/checkeol/annotate/head%3A/__init__.py

Everything works, however, I would like to additionally add a command line option, which could disable this hook, e.g.,

If I called 
`bzr commit --ignore-my-hook`
it would skip my pre-commit hook.

I know that there exists also option `--no-plugins` but that disables all plugins.
I would really like to know if this is possible. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable:

```
BZR_DISABLE_PLUGIN=yourplugin
```

to disable one specific plugin.

Or alternatively, you can add functionality to your hook to not do anything if a certain option or environment variable is set. You can set configuration options from the command line, which you can access from the hook. T

There is no other custom command line input you can provide to the hook.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question was however more about that if the pre-commit hooks (or any hooks) can have input parameters, in general, which can be called directly from command line. I assume it must be possible, but unfortunately I had no luck to find out.

Comment: I've clarified the answer.

Comment: @jelmer is right that hooks cannot modify command-line parameters.  But your plugin *can* override the commit command and substitute its own version that supports additional parameters.